# How would I return an array of modified objects without returning the original objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am making a random maze generator and I have gotten everything to work, except for the return statement. My original plan for this in the end is to be able to test some maze solving algorithms on this, so displaying it is nice, which it does, but having access to the maze as code is a necessity. The function itself modifies the objects in the array and works, but when returned, the objects are all in their original state.

```
//This is the code with the irrelevant stuff removed
function generate() {
  var maze = []
  for(let y = 0; y < tiles[1]; y++) {
    let tempArr = [];
    for(let x = 0; x < tiles[0]; x++) {
      //l,u,r,and d are all whether or not you can pass through that side of the tile, v is whether or not the tile has been visited by the actual generation
      tempArr.push([{l:true,u:true,r:true,d:true,v:false}]);
    }
    maze.push(tempArr);
    //After this point, the array that is returned does not change
  }

  //Builds the walls on the edge of the square
  for(let y = 0; y < maze.length; y++) {
    for(let x = 0; x < maze[y].length; x++) {
      if(y == 0) {
        maze[y][x].u = false;
      }
      if(x == 0) {
        maze[y][x].l = false;
      }
      if(y == tiles[1]-1) {
        maze[y][x].r = false;
      }
      if(x == tiles[0]-1) {
        maze[y][x].d = false
      }
    }
  }

  let _x = 0;
  let _y = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i < tiles[0]*tiles[1]; i++) {
    //None of these changes are visible in the returned array
    maze[_y][_x].v = true;
    let running = true;
    while(running) {
      maze[_y][_x].v = true;
      let random = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1;
      if(random == 1) {//This is repeated for 2, 3, and 4
        if(maze[_y][_x-1] && !maze[_y][_x-1].v) {
          maze[_y][_x].l = true;
          maze[_y][_x-1].r = true;
          _x -= 1;
          continue;
        } else if(maze[_y][_x+1] && !maze[_y][_x+1].v) {
          maze[_y][_x].r = true;
          maze[_y][_x+1].l = true;
          _x += 1;
          continue;
        } else {
          random++
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return maze; //This returns the original array, regardless of any changes made
}
```

This does not get me any errors, but in the case of a 3 x 3 maze I would expect a result of:

```
[[{u:false,l:false,d:false,r:true,v:true}],[{u:false,l:true,d:false,r:true,v:true}],[{u:false,l:true,d:true,r:false,v:true}]],
[[{u:false,l:false,d:true,r:true,v:true}],[{u:false,l:true,d:false,r:true,v:true}],[{u:true,l:true,d:false,r:false,v:true}]],
[[{u:true,l:false,d:false,r:true,v:true}],[{u:false,l:true,d:false,r:true,v:true}],[{u:false,l:true,d:false,r:false,v:true}]]
```

but get an array consisting of only:

```
{d:true,l:true,r:true,u:true,v:false}
```

Comment: Is `generate` the function that leaves the object in an undesirable state, or is it your solver function?

Comment: Welcome to SO! There's a lot of duplicate code here (each `if(random == x)` block can be rolled into a helper function with offset vars, for example), and the snippet isn't really a [mcve]. Can you post working code that reproduces the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I figured it out, it is because it was a 3 dimensional array and I was treating it as 2d